# Can this be achieved through Aggregation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have achieved what I want but I'm not convinced it is the best approach. This is my model:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 3)
    rate1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 3)
    rate2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 3)
```

This is my view:

```
sum = {}
bad_rating = None
rate = foo.objects.values('user').distinct().annotate(r=Avg("rate"), r1 = Avg("rate1"), r2= Avg("rate2"))
for r in rate:
    sum[r['user']]=r['r']+r['r1']+r['r2']
bad_rating = sorted(sum.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Basically, I'm getting average of `rate`, `rate1` and `rate2` grouped by distinct users. Once I have gained the average of these three fields associated with distinct users, I want to add them all together, and keep the user association.

In my case, I have a queryset at the beginning, then I store it in a dictionary, then I store it in a tupple list (because it allows me to order it and gain the lowest rating, or highest rating).

Is it possible to achieve the same results through Django Queryset and aggregation?

In example:
My Queryset result:

```
<QuerySet [{'r': 1.0, 'r2': 3.0, 'user': 16, 'r3': 5.0}, {'r': 4.333333333333333, 'r2': 2.1666666666666665, 'user': 17, 'r3': 5.0}, {'r': 2.0, 'r1': 2.0, 'user': 18, 'r2': 2.0}]>
```

Instead I would like a queryset that would produce the following results:

```
<QuerySet [{16: 5.4}, {17: 3.5}, {18: 4.0}]>
```

`16` being the user id, and 5.4 being `avg(rate)+avg(rate1)+avg(rate2)`.

Comment: Maybe it can be made into a [query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/)? I wonder if `F()` can accept other expressions like `Avg` as arguments.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for the direction, I will give it a try and post answer if I manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @9000 comment I manage to solve the problem:

```
rate = foo.objects.values('user').distinct().annotate(r=Avg("rate"), r1= Avg("rate1"), r2= Avg("rate2")).annotate(a = F('r')+F('r1')+F('r2')).order_by('a')[:5]
```

The only issue I have now is that it returns the user id, which is useful, but it would be much more convenient if it returned user instead, so I can use it directly in the template.

Thanks,