# Why does dict.key returns value in Template but not in Views

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Continuing from previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686875/can-this-be-achieved-through-aggregation/42776141#42776141).

I have a queryset that I can get the value through key in Template, but if I try identical steps in Views.py, I get:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

My query is:

```
rate = foo.objects.values('user').distinct().annotate(r=Avg("rate"), r1= Avg("rate1"), r2= Avg("rate2")).annotate(a = F('r')+F('r1')+F('r2')).order_by('a')[:5]
```

The above query returns:

```
<QuerySet [{'user': 18, 'r': 2.0, 'r1': 2.0, 'a': 10.0, 'r2': 2.0}, {'user': 16, 'r': 1.0, 'r1': 5.0, 'a': 15.0, 'r2': 4.0}, {'user': 17, 'r': 4.333333333333333, 'r1': 5.0, 'a': 20.833333333333332, 'r2': 4.833333333333333}]>
```

In template, if I do this, it returns the user_id:

```
{% for r in rate %}
    {{ r.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

but if I do similar in view:

```
for r in rate:
    foo = r.user
```

I will get a 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'.

My objective is to get the user object, so I'm trying to get the user_id and through it get a list of the users so I can use them to display information in template.

Looking for a reason as to why it works in template, and not in Views.

Also looking for an alternative to the query which would return user object, rather than user_id. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a dictionary, so you have to do `r.get('user')` or `r['user']`. Django just uses [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#variables) in templates.

Comment: Is it possible to get this as a result: `<QuerySet [{'user': <userobject>...` rather than `<QuerySet [{'user': 18...` ? Thanks for the response.

Comment: That I'm not certain about, but my instinct is to say no - `values()` will only return a `dict`. Is there a reason you're using `values()` and not just a normal `QuerySet`? Seems like that is what you want - then you could do `r.user.email`, `r.user.first_name`, etc.

Comment: There's no reason, I did not think it was possible. I thought about using `filter`, but that can't be possible because `filter` requires a condition, what would be the condition in the above case? I thought about `all()` but could not figure out how to get average of distinct users, rather than all.